# Correct AJAX URL to post to in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've just got off the phone with a corporate client who is concerned about the URL our website is making AJAX posts to. He thinks it is dodgy that it posts to an admin UR and could post a security risk.

It's a Wordpress website which posts to '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' which I thought was pretty standard. I'd include it in code like the below.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Are there any other alternative URLs to to post to using AJAX in Wordpress? Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: You can check this thread https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/ajaxurl-not-defined-on-front-end

Comment: admin-ajax.php is the endpoint for AJAX request. Does your data contain a nonce? If it does you should explain to your client about nonces and security. If it does not than you do have a security risk.